# Reactjs, error send data to post with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

hi I am trying to post a form with email and password, but I have an error in the function that sends the data, that function you see in the image

[image]
action.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const createUser =(usuariosBody, callback) => {
  return function(dispatch){
      dispatch({type: 'CREATE_USER_REQUEST'});
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/users', usuariosBody)
      .then((response)=>{
            dispatch({type: 'CREATE_USER_SUCCESS', payload:response.data})
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback(null, response.data);
            }
         })
    }
}
```

component.jsx

```
class  LoginComponent extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    }
    render(){
        return(
          <section className="form-sign brown lighten-5">
              <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                  <input ref="email" placeholder='Email' />
                  <input type="password"  ref="password"  />
                  <Button   type='submit' >send</Button>
              </form>
          </section>
        )
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        this.preventDefault();

        const email = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.email).value.trim();
        const password = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.password).value.trim();

        // create a user object
        const user = {
          email,
          password
        };

        // call the action

        this.props.createUser(user, function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log(res);
            }
        });
    }
}
export default LoginComponent;
```

container.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {createUser} from '../action/action.js';
import {LoginComponent} from '../component/loginComponent.jsx';

class CreateUserContainer extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){

    }

    render (){
        return (<LoginComponent createUser={this.props.createUser} />);
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(store) {
    return {};
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({
        createUser:CreateUser
    }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateUserContainer);
```

thanks for your help

Comment: i changed but is same error

Comment: I was editing your question for readability and I noticed you miss the closing mark for form

Comment: o yes, I fixed it but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `{CreateUser}` and trying to use `{createUser}` in the container.jsx file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i changed it but it did not work

Comment: Can you check what is `this` in the `handleSubmit` function? (using console.log) and check if there is any property inside `props`

Comment: show:  LoginComponent {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, _reactInternalInstance: ReactCompositeComponentWrapper…}

Comment: Make sure this line `function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({
        createUser:CreateUser
    }, dispatch)
}` is with `createUser` (lowerCase - should be `createUser: createUser`)

Comment: the file name is action.js? You are importing createUser.js. Make sure the file name is correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mapDispatchToProps` instead of `matchDispatchToProps` and also 
use `CreateUser` in you `mapDispatchToProps` function since you imported it as CreateUser

```
class CreateUserContainer extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount(){

    }
    render (){
        return(
            <LoginComponent createUser={this.props.createUser} />
        )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({
        createUser:CreateUser
    }, dispatch)
}
```

Also your class must implement the constructor to inherit the props

One more thing is that your handleSubmit function in LoginComponent is not bound

```
class  LoginComponent extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

You can also try and `console.log(this.props)` in your `LoginComponent` to see if it receives the `createUser` function

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, i made the changes, but the error is same

Comment: I would advise you not to edit your question without mentioning the change since that was a part in you code that was also causing the problem and may help someone in future

Comment: Updated the answer, can you check it once more

Comment: when i try console.log(this.props); show Object {}, but i made your changes, and not work

Comment: can you try and console.log(this.props) in the  CreateUserContainer components componetDidMount function and see if you get the function there

Comment: When you try to `import {createUser} from '../action/createUser.js';`. I think it should be `import {createUser} from '../action/action.js';` since you have mentioned the code in action.js. Make sure it is the correct path and you can see it in your mapDispatchToProps function

Comment: What doesnt work, can you see the createUser function in mapDispatchToProps function . If not then the only problem could be that you are not importing it properly considering that you have default exported it. It should be `import createUser from '../action/action.js'`

Comment: Already verify and I am importing well, I have a question, when I make the router, I must import the component of the container?

Comment: In your routing you have to import just the container `import createUserContainer from '[path_to_container]/container.jsx'`. You should add the code for the routing in your question too.